# How to use regex to append string to the matched results

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to replace `0-1.` with `0-1.<br>` how do i do that?

update:

Sorry for my vague question. You guys misunderstood me. '0-1.' is the pattern i want to replace, which means the pattern should be like `"/(\d)+(-)*(\d)*\./"` and the string may be '1.' '0-1.' or something that expression could represent

Comment: Please provide a more complete example and what you have tried so far. Currently, a valid answer could be `$match .= '<br>';`.

Comment: Use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Comment: As a note on terminology, regular expressions can only match strings, not modify them.  A function like PHP's `preg_replace` uses a regular expression to identify which parts of a string to replace, but a string (with some interpolation options) to specify what to replace it with.

Comment: Is this question not answered? See  https://stackoverflow.com/a/7468949/3832970, please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
preg_replace("/(\d+(?:-\d+)?\.)/", "$1<br>", $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a standard PHP function:

```
str_replace('0-1.', '0-1.<br>', $yourString);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_replace` like this:

```
preg_replace("/(0-1\.)/", "$1<br>", $string);
```

or, as you know the substitution already:

```
preg_replace("/0-1\./", "0-1.<br>", $string);
```